# How to navigate pages using a child UserControl button using AvaloniaUI

Tags: reactiveui, avaloniaui

New to AvaloniaUI / ReactiveUI, but not to WPF. I'm trying to play around with AvaloniaUI to see if I want to port my entire WPF project over to it, but I've ran into a little bit of a hurdle. I've found many examples of binding commands to 'self', eg. UserControl binding in UserControlModel, MainWindow binding in MainWindowModel, but nothing on a child UserControl binding to Parent model command. I've based my MainWindowModel.cs after one of the basic examples given by AvaloniaUI as shown. I basically want a button on a page to select which page in the Pages[] list to go to. But for now just go to the next one in the list. In WPF I would just the NavigationService and URI to nav, but wanted to try out this paradigm in Avalonia UI.

`MainWindowModel.cs`

```csharp
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            // Set current page to first on start up
            _CurrentPage = Pages[0];

            // Create Observables which will activate to deactivate our commands based on CurrentPage state
            var canNavNext = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.CurrentPage.CanNavigateNext);
            var canNavPrev = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.CurrentPage.CanNavigatePrevious);

            NavigateNextCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(NavigateNext, canNavNext);
            NavigatePreviousCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(NavigatePrevious, canNavPrev);
        }

        // A read.only array of possible pages
        private readonly PageViewModelBase[] Pages = 
        { 
            new FirstPageViewModel(),
            new SecondPageViewModel(),
            new ThirdPageViewModel()
        };

        // The default is the first page
        private PageViewModelBase _CurrentPage;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the current page. The property is read-only
        /// </summary>
        public PageViewModelBase CurrentPage
        {
            get { return _CurrentPage; }
            private set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _CurrentPage, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a command that navigates to the next page
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand NavigateNextCommand { get; }

        private void NavigateNext()
        {
            // get the current index and add 1
            var index = Pages.IndexOf(CurrentPage) + 1;

            //  /!\ Be aware that we have no check if the index is valid. You may want to add it on your own. /!\
            CurrentPage = Pages[index];
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a command that navigates to the previous page
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand NavigatePreviousCommand { get; }

        private void NavigatePrevious()
        {
            // get the current index and subtract 1
            var index = Pages.IndexOf(CurrentPage) - 1;

            //  /!\ Be aware that we have no check if the index is valid. You may want to add it on your own. /!\
            CurrentPage = Pages[index];
        }
    }
```

The example binds the navigation buttons in `MainWindow.axaml`

```csharp
 <TransitioningContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPage}" />

 <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="5"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right">
     <Button Command="{Binding NavigatePreviousCommand}" Content="Back" />
     <Button Command="{Binding NavigateNextCommand}" Content="Next" />
</StackPanel>
```

I would like to bind to these commands in childView Page buttons. Is there a way to do that? Or do I need to link up an Event handler to signal to the Parent (MainWindow) to do it? And if so what does a basic example look like?

Thanks!

I've tried a number of route examples but none are related to the Parent-Child relationship.